# What is the right way to upload CentOS packages to Nexus 3?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I uploaded CentOS-8.1 AppStream and BaseOS packages to Nexus-3 with curl.

When I try to install httpd using Nexus-3 yum repository, it gives me

> "Package httpd-2.4.37 requires mod_httpd2 but none of providers can be
>   installed."

First I thought I missed some packages to upload. But that was not the case.

Then I mount CentOS iso file and tried to install httpd using local repository, success!

Problem is `repomd.xml` files are different. Nexus creates it's own `repomd.xml` files after a package is uploaded which create conflicts.

In addition `"yum group list"` does not work with Nexus.

What is the right way to upload CentOS packages to Nexus repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of uploading all rpm to `yum(hosted)` repository, I uploaded all directories and files to `raw(hosted)` repository. Works fine!